# Child position differs from assigned if container has non-integer (%) position

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have centered `(position: absolute; left: 50%; margin: -50px;)` 100px width div (container).

It has **absolutely** positioned child div with `overflow: hidden`, its size is `100x2000 px` (such height is for test purposes, as described below).

There is an image in child div, it is **absolutely** positioned. 
The image is `3100x100 px,` it contains frames of animation.

I am animating this image by changing its `style.left` from 0 to -1100px, step is 100px.
Everything is fine, but I encounter weird issue when body width is not even.

It can happen if there is scrollbar and the scrollbar has odd width (it happens for me on Chrome/Win32 for example).
In this case image visually shifts by 1 pixel horizontally as soon as animated image goes through screen edge (for 1920x1080 it happens roughly at 9-10 frame of animation).
I can't find workaround for this behavior.

Working example reproducing the problem can be found [here](http://lorgame.ru/animtest.htm)

Child div height is set to 2000px to make sure scrollbar is visible.
If your scrollbar has even width, you can reproduce the problem by resizing your browser window to odd width.

Comment: you should document better your question, can you paste somenthing to jsfiddle.net for example?

Comment: could I see the css and jquery code please

Comment: Fiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/PjHFc/ The problem seems to be Chrome/Webkit only.

Comment: Why you do not use gif animation?

Comment: wow, didn't know about jsfiddle. sorry. will use it from now ;)

gif animation is definitely not the thing i need in my project. gif has many cons, for example 8 bit palette and only binary transparency...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this seems like a bug in Chrome. When percentages are defined in integers, they behave rather unexpectedly. Try to define the position as a decimal instead:

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 49.99999%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

I tested this on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjHFc/3/) and it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a dirty hack, but it does the job and does not require to rewrite whole animation code or re-positioning .outer each time window is resized as suggested in other answers.
I'll mark this as accepted answer. It is dirty but I have to use it.
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

That happens because of the browsers rounding engines. Webkit apparently has some problems with `50%` on even and odd widths.

One way to overcome the issue - re-position the `.outer` element based on window width

```
document.getElementById( 'outer' ).style.left = Math.floor( window.innerWidth / 2 ) + 'px';
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PjHFc/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I think re-positioning .outer each time window is resized (or even with each frame of each animation on the page) is not a good way to go.

Comment: you can move that line out of the loop, so it will run once only - http://jsfiddle.net/PjHFc/4/

Comment: this way it won't be recalculated automatically when the user resizes the browser window. And doing positioning in JS code is usually bad idea performance-wise.

Comment: if you try to resize the window you'll see that it works.. I agree that doing it in a loop is not the best idea but a single JS re-positioning won't have *any* effect on the performance :)

Comment: how can that work if it is _single_ JS re-positioning?
unless you put that in resize handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `.inner img position` to `relative` and update your javascript. I made changes for you, so here is your solved code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #000000;
            }
            .outer {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -50px;
            }
            .inner {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100px;
                height: 2000px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .inner img {
                position: relative;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
                <img src="http://lorgame.ru/test.png" id="img">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            var framesCount = 30;
            var framesCurrent = 0;
            var framesMoveLeft = true;
            var img = document.getElementById('img');
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                if(framesMoveLeft == true){
                  framesCurrent++;
                  img.style.left = (img.offsetLeft - 100) + 'px';
                  if(framesCurrent == framesCount) framesMoveLeft = false;
                } else { // Move right
                  framesCurrent--;
                  img.style.left = (img.offsetLeft + 100) + 'px';
                  if(framesCurrent == 0) framesMoveLeft = true;
                }
            }, 100);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. My code was simplified, animations can be more complicated and the "frames" array was there for a reason. However of course I can alter your code to make it playing any animation with specified frames order. 
So I think I'll use this approach in further projects. However I'll have to stick to "dirty hack" solution suggested below for this project because I can't afford re-writing all animation code atm.
Thank you anyway for the nice idea!

Comment: I would share bounty between your answer and Kaivosukeltaja's answer, but it seems I can't. Sorry :(